# How to find a double quoted string using grep and regex?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find all the occurrences of the string "5.1" in all files under a certain directory.
I've tried using the following command but it finds none:

```
#grep -Re[5]+\.+[1] .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing there must be a space between `-Re` and the pattern. Then your pattern should be quoted to keep the shell from globbing the '[]' character ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression doesn't make sense to me.  It seems like you're looking for:

```
grep -R '5\.1' .
```

Or if you want to include the `"` characters:

```
grep -R '"5\.1"' .
```

But I don't see anything related to those in your original post, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need e regex for that, so fgrep is simpler to construct and executes quicker

```
fgrep -R '"5.1"' .
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a fixed string recursively would be

```
grep -fR '"5.1"' .
```

(if you really meant including the double quotes).

Note that the `-R` option is not POSIX, so may not be available. In that case, the portable solution is

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -f '"5.1"'
```